# How to make my web application that uses mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup on a phone/tablet?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, touch, mouseevent

I have written an open-source mathematics application that plots fractal images.  It is hosted on my personal web site: http://danielsadventure.info/html5fractal/index.html.  If you click this link, please be aware that Javascript performance is atrocious in IE (even the most recent version at the time of this writing).

As you may know, fractal images contain a literally infinite amount of detail and one of the features of my application is that you can select a region of the image with the mouse and zoom in on it (up until you reach the limits of 64-bit floating-point computation).

The fractal image is displayed on an HTML5 canvas element.  There is a second canvas element overlaid on top of the image on which the selected region is marked. (This allows for the selected region to change without redrawing the image)

The code for the mouse selection is simple: the application simply listens for the mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup events.  When mousedown is fired, a variable is set indicating that the mouse button is down.  When mousemove is fired and the mouse button is down, a square is drawn on the selection canvas to indicate what region will be selected when the user releases the button.  Finally, when mouseup is fired, the application records where the mouse button was pressed and released.  If the user is satisfied with the resulting selection, he can zoom in on it.

My question for StackOverflow is: "How can I provide functionality like this on touch-screen systems, such as iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows 8?"

Comment: Have you looked at touch events? http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent

Comment: @GameAlchemist, there is so much information out there about this sort of thing, it's hard to tell where to start.  There are the raw events, various libraries to handle them, and browser inconsistencies.  I have found that asking on a site such as this often saves a lot of time and frustration by getting a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: I understand your intent. Yet it is not clear in your post why you wouldn't just update your code to use touchStart/Move/End instead of MouseDown/Up/Move. And stack Overflow is not about software recommandation, otherwise the question will be flagged 'too broad' or opinion based. And indeed you might have just as many opinions as answers... When you'll have some issue with either a lib or the code you made-up the question will be more suited for Stack Overflow. Good luck for your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed to using [JQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), you could use the [vmousedown](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/), [vmouseup](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseup/), and [vmousemove](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousemove/) events.  I haven't used them myself yet, but it looks like using those abstracts away the difference between touches and mouse clicks.  So you would probably only need to modify your event handler instead of writing new ones.

If you would really rather avoid using JQuery mobile, you can look into [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent), which is what JQuery mobile abstracts away.

Comment: Did I hear that jQuery and jQuery-mobile have merged into one project?

Comment: I think it was jQuery UI and jQuery mobile that merged.

Comment: So then, if I've already added the most recent jQuery-UI to my application, I shouldn't need any more libraries to use the vmouse* events.

Comment: You should test to make sure, but yeah.  It says they merged here: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/08/

Answer (score -1):

You can use Jquery Mobile or other javascript mobile framework